# Concise way of getting date from java.util.date

Tags: datetime, date, java.util.date

I'm trying to retrieve the date only from a `java.util.date`. I know I can set the time to 0 but I'm searching for a cleaner, more concise way if possible. Does this exist?

Thanks! 
Krt_Malta

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner way is to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) to start with, where there are separate concepts of LocalDate, LocalTime, LocalDateTime, DateTime, Instant etc.

You *can* translate between java.util.Date and the Joda types, but I would suggest you stick to using Joda for as much of the code as you can, and only translate when you really need to.

Sorry if you'd hoped to avoid an extra library - but Joda is *so* much better than the built-in API, it's well worth investing in the effort IMO. Note that within the Java types you'll need to determine which time zone you're interested in - java.util.Date defines an instant in time, which may occur in as many as three different dates around the world depending on your time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the `truncate` method in the `DateUtils` library. You put in the date and the field up to which you are interested (in this case `CALENDAR.DAY_OF_MONTH`). The rest will be set to 0. Effectively:

```
DateUtils.truncate(Calendar.getInstance(), Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).getTime()
```

did the job.

More info about the method is at: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#truncate%28java.lang.Object,%20int%29